# urlencode is stripping html tags from '</a>' to '</a'

Tags: php

I am sending a message encoded in base64 as get in url like this:

```
$message         = 'title=' . $title . '&text=' . $text;
                $encoded_message = urlencode( base64_encode( $message ) );

                $ch = curl_init(); 

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/catch.php?string=' . $encoded_message ); 

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

                $output = curl_exec($ch); 

                curl_close($ch);
```

And in catch.php I have this to decode the encoded message:

```
$string = $_GET['string'];

if ($string != '') {
    // continue
} else {
    exit;
}

$decoded_string = base64_decode( urldecode( $string ) );

parse_str($decoded_string, $string_arr);
```

But sometimes the tags like `</a>` end like `</a`

How to fix that?

Comment: Don't send the string itself as a GET argument, use POST instead

Comment: But that file with catching code is on another server. They are not on the same server.

Comment: Sending stuff with post is complicated https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post get should work for me the only problem is that it sometimes remove the '>' for some unknown reason. Sometimes it work good.

Comment: What does it matter whether it's on the same server or a different server? That doesn't make any difference to GET or POST

Comment: But while GET is "easy" it's also simplistic..... it's limited in size, it's limited in capabilities, it's causing you this problem..... none of those issues or potential issues would exist with POST (and using a CURL wrapper like Guzzle, it's no more difficult than a GET)

Comment: But urlencode shouldn't remove characters from the GET string, something else is responsible for that

Comment: What about the order of urlencode ( base64_encode ) VS base64_decode ( urldecode) ? Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Neither urlencode/urldecode nor base64_encode/base64_decode should cause data to be lost.... excessive string length might, and both of those will increase the length of the string

Comment: As you would rather struggle with this approach than use POST, do some basic debugging of the URL that's sent and that which is requested

Comment: I would be interested to see the raw GET data before anything is done with it. But agree that POST should not be ruled out.

Answer (score 2):

On the server don't urldecode $string, $_GET does it for you.

If the base64 value has '+' characters, the second urldecode process will mess it.

```
$decoded_string = base64_decode( $string );
```